# Pay with PayFlow and Refund with REST

Tags: rest, paypal, payflowpro

I want ask,may i Pay with Payment Advanced what use Payflow,but refund use REST.I do this,but when i fefund,i get "Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Stream was not readable.".Now i want know is Payflow can use with REST,is anybody success do this.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your REST request in general.  Have you gotten other REST calls to function properly?

Comment: when i pay with REST,and refund with REST,ti's OK.when i pay with payflow,refund with REST,it's wrong.

Comment: I think that answers your question then doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot pay with Payflow and the refund with REST.  The REST API uses a separate set of (resource) ids, this means that the REST API refund operation expects an id that comes from a payment made with the REST API.